# Issue in width of the chart

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I"m working on a project in which the design is similar to that of the one in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/1/).

Side navigation of the left with toggle option and the chart on to the right side.

What's happening is the chart responsiveness is awesome and it's perfect when I resize the window.

But in the my project I have a toggle button to toggle the `navigation` bar in the left side which is working fine.

When I hide the navigation bar. The div width becomes 100% of the screen but the width of the chart remains the same unless I do some action on the window like re-sizing.

In the fiddle you can find the prob what I'm facing when you toggle the sidebar.

Note : border given to the div to indicate the width of the `div` on toggling the sidebar.

I did google on this but I found nothing.

If any of facing this same prob and found any solution. Please do help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even i had faced the same problem when u toggle the chart gets cramped
I made the width of the chart width fixed by using 
`highcharts({chart: {width: 400}....`  if u done want responsive things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart seem to be redrawn/resized on a window resize event so you could trigger that event after toggling the sidebar.

```
$('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('toggle-sidebar');
    $(window).resize();
})
```

[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/2/)

Comment: Is there any possibilities that we can animate the width of the chart?

Comment: I haven't seen a built in method for animating the width so you'd probably have to build something yourself for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `reflow` function

http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/3/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

Comment: Then you need to use setSize (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize)

Comment: But here we don't fix the width. It's dynamic.

Comment: you can het width of div by $('#container').width(); and $('#container').height(); http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/4/

Comment: I got a bug in it. Function is getting called for the second time I click on the toggle button in my project.

Comment: For the first click it remains the same width. And for the second click the width gets more than 100%. And vice versa

Comment: I've added transition for the sidebar toggling using css. Here's where the problem starts. Please look into this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/5/).

Comment: Here's the new [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613911/highcharts-issue-with-the-chart-reflow-function).