# Highcharts - Issue with the chart reflow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/6/).

I had issue `width` the chart with on toggling the sidebar.

And I got it solved with the help of SO from this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602167/issue-in-width-of-the-chart).

Now I'm facing with another bug. That is if I add some transition in toggling the sidebar.

The chart width gets vice-versa.

In the above fiddle you can find it.

If I remove the `transition`, it does works fine.

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBUv9/4/) which works fine without the sidebar transition.

Help me out to solve this bug.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an issue with the timing.
You are trying to reflow the chart before the animation is finished.
Try with `setTimeout(reflowChart, 200)` as I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/hige/J4Uz2/

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: This is quite a dirty solution! What happens when your sidebar animation suddenly takes 1 second to fully expand?
I would recommend you use javascript to handle your css3 animations which allows for the sidebar to emit an event once the animation is done and then you can reflow the chart! :) 

Hope it can help someone to design clean code!

Comment: @thinkwinwin , it will be good if you can give an example satisfying your answer as i didn't understand. Thanks.