# Angular2 calling reflow chart does not works

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have an Angular2 appplication with Highcharts framework integrated on

My problem is that I have to resize the chart when a div is toggled, very similar to this post:

[Highcharts - Issue with the chart reflow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613911/highcharts-issue-with-the-chart-reflow-function)

[original chart size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUS7T.png)

when a try to show a other section, i change the div size of the chart

[new chart size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8U0n.png)

as you can see, the chart is not resized.

as the documentation says, if I resizes my browser, then the chart is fit into the new size area

I tried to implement the reflow() call in my Graph component:

Component definition

```
    @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'graph',
    template: `
        <div style="width:100%">
            <chart (load)="guardarChart($event.context)" [options]="options"></chart>
        </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./graph.css']
})
```

guardarChart and reflow methods

```
redraw() {
    setTimeout(this.chart.reflow(), 2000);
}

guardarChart(chartInstance: Highcharts.Chart) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
}
```

ccs code

```
chart {
    display: block;
}
```

if I change the redraw method in order to call any other method of Chart, it works, for example, if I call the setSize method, the chart changes its size, but the reflow() method does not work

Is there any other confgiurtaion into the chart options that I'am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: correct me is this correct `setTimeout(this.chart.reflow(), 2000);` or it should be `setTimeout(() => { this.chart.reflow()}, 2000);` ?

Comment: Can you set up a live example of the issue, e.g. on plunkr?

Comment: Mahesh, thank you very much, you are right, I had wrong my setTimeout call sintaxis. Now my chart is resizing.

Comment: Thanks for your response morganfree.